# msck repair table sync partitions - partitions are added to the metastore, but not deleted from metastore

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive, hdfs

**partitions are added to the metastore, but not deleted**

PARTITIONED BY (
`type` smallint) - the error appears when the data type is in the "partitioned by" column **smallint or bigint**, there is no error with string

I use the command **msck repair table table_name sync partitions**

such an error comes out - Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=08S01,code=1)

**LOGS**: [pool-8-thread-199]: metastore.PartFilterExprUtil - Unable to make the expression tree *from expression string* [(type = 346S)]Error parsing partition filter; lexer error: null; exception NoViableAltException(13@[])[pool-8-thread-199]: metastore.ObjectStore - Falling back to ORM path due to direct SQL failure (this is not an error): java.lang.**String cannot be cast to java.lang.Short**

*from expression string* - what does it mean?

what does it want to convert into a string?

i use hdfs (not ozone)

parameter - *set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;* does not work

parameter - *set hive.msck.path.validation=skip;* does not work

analyze table compute statistic - does not work